# Formatting JSON data to a single line

Tags: json, formatting

I am having some requirements:

1. Each json data point must be on a single line
2. Each json data point must be separated by a newline character
3. Additionally, if possible each data point must be separated by an {"index":{}} statement

I am having roughly 1000 json data points. Here is an example of what three look like:

```
{
  "str field": "some string",
  "int field": 12345,
  "bool field": True
}{
  "str field": "another string",
  "int field": 42,
  "bool field": False
}{
  "str field": "random string",
  "int field": 3856452,
  "bool field": True
}
```

But I need it to look like so:

```
{"index":{}}
{"str field": "some string", "int field": 12345, "bool field": True}
{"index":{}}
{"str field": "another string", "int field": 42, "bool field": False}
{"index":{}}
{"str field": "random string", "int field": 3856452, "bool field": True}
```

Currently i am using http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ along with notepad++ to accomplish this but it is not always working properly and struggles with larger datasets. I would prefer **not** to use a third party website but rather accomplish the same using an IDE such as VS Code or IntelliJ.

If you are familiar with elasticsearch I am essentially formatting the data for bulk indexing operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `jq`

```
$ echo "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}" | jq -c . 
{"foo":"bar"}
```

`-c` for compact